# $(this) and event.target different but should be the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that wires up the click event function to the submit button. I am aware that `event.target` and `this` are not always the same (as I understand it depends where the event was attached to and who actually fired it) but in this case the event was attached to the button and the button also fired it, so they should be the same. Or am I wrong?

```
 modals.init = function () {
    // wire up submit() function to the submit button
    modals.config.$submitBtn.on('click', submit);
  };

  function submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    alert(event.target.id); // fine
    alert($this.id); // undefined
}
```

Comment: $this is a jQuery wrapped set, you need to use $this.attr('id') or reference the first element $this[0].id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `$this.attr("id")` (jQuery element) or `this.id` (DOM element)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, then `this === event.target`.

But if you wrap it into a `jQuery` wrapper, it has no `id` property any more. You can either use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')` to get the attribute or `$(this).prop('id')` to get `this.id`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `this`  is bounded to be the element clicked, so there is no `.id` property, it's the jQuery representation of the element clicked.

Answer (score 1):

With the code `$(this)` you generate a jquery object and you have to use the jquery functions: `alert($this.attr("id));`.